# How to remamp json with ksql in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

The `INPUT_DATA` topic in Kafka gets all data messages posted with the same JSON schema:

```
{
  "year": {
    "month": {
      "day": {
        "hour": string
        }
      }
    }
}
```

First I create Kafka Stream using a persistent ksql query. This stream will be reading the data messages posted to `INPUT_TOPIC`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM INPUT_STREAM (year STRUCT<month STRUCT<day STRUCT<hour VARCHAR>>>) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'INPUT_TOPIC', VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON');
```

I confirm using Confluent Kafka web UI that the `INPUT_STREAM` was properly created with its schema defined to support the data-messages that follow schema

`{year: {month: {day: hour: string}}}}`

[image]

Next I need to create a second `OUTPUT_STREAM`. This stream will be created to read the data messages from `INPUT_STREAM`. It will remap the original input JSON messages by removing the top level `year` field. So instead of being 4 levels deep the resulted messages will be 3 levels deep, for example: 1.month > 2.day > 3.hour :

```
{
  "month": {
    "day": {
      "hour": string
      }
    }
}
```

`OUTPUT_STREAM` will be writing the re-mapped JSON messages to its own `OUTPUT_TOPIC`. The message schema for this stream should be 3 levels deep:

[image]

So the entire setup is made of two Topics and two Streams:

`INPUT_TOPIC` > `INPUT_STREAM` > `OUTPUT_STREAM` > `OUTPUT_TOPIC`

I go ahead and put together `ksql` statement posted below. It attempts to remap `YEAR->MONTH->DAY->HOUR` as `STRUCT<MONTH STRUCT<DAY STRUCT<HOUR VARCHAR>>>`:

```
CREATE STREAM OUTPUT_STREAM WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='OUTPUT_TOPIC', REPLICAS=3) AS SELECT YEAR->MONTH->DAY->HOUR HOUR STRUCT<MONTH STRUCT<DAY STRUCT<HOUR VARCHAR>>> FROM INPUT_DATA_STREAM EMIT CHANGES;
```

But it fails with the error `Line 1:8: no viable alternative at input`

Is it possible to remap the values from input data to a different json schema using ksql and streams or tables?

Comment: If you want to remove the top field, you only need to `SELECT YEAR->MONTH`. I.e. select _that struct_. The schema should be automatic...

Comment: Please post it as answer with ksql statement showing this suggestion.

Comment: I don't use ksql, but did that work? Doesn't really answer the error you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT YEAR->MONTH->DAY->HOUR` is selecting only that inner-most `hour` string field.

To select the month struct, you only need `SELECT YEAR->MONTH`, and that'll bring along the nested data within that struct.

The schema should be inferred from the original stream, so you shouldn't need to redefine it.

Comment: This works as: `CREATE STREAM OUTPUT_STREAM WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='OUTPUT_TOPIC', REPLICAS=3) AS SELECT YEAR->MONTH->DAY DAY FROM INPUT_STREAM EMIT CHANGES;`

Comment: That output is "3 levels deep"? Reading that query literally, I'd only expect that to return `{"day": {"hour": ... }}`

Comment: To remove`year` as the topmost field:
`CREATE STREAM OUTPUT_STREAM WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='OUTPUT_TOPIC', REPLICAS=3) AS SELECT YEAR->MONTH MONTH FROM INPUT_STREAM EMIT CHANGES;`